# Cloning a table and modifying the clone modifies the original element

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a huge table that I want to clone and divide the clone into 2 separate tables, keeping the original table unchanged.

Say the original table is called #MainTable with 10 columns

I create a clone #CloneTable which initially also has all the 10 columns of #MainTable

Now, I change #CloneTable, such that #CloneTable has the first 5 columns and another table #RemainingClone has the remaining 5 columns

Now, what happens here is that suddenly my original table #MainTable also loses 5 columns and updates to retain only those columns that #CloneTable has.

Shouldn't #MainTable be unaffected by changes being made to #CloneTable?

EDIT 1: I am using the jquery clone(), as the Tags indicate.

#### EDIT 2: Here's some code -

```
 $("#MainTable").clone().attr('id', 'CloneTable').appendTo("#printingDiv");
 splitTable();


function splitTable() {
     var divider = 5;
     var $tableOne = $('table').attr('id','CloneTable');
     var $tableTwo = $tableOne.clone().attr('id','RemainingClone').appendTo('#printingDiv');

     // number of rows in table
     var numOfRows = $tableOne.find('tr').length;

     // select rows of each table
     var $tableOneRows = $tableOne.find('tr');
     var $tableTwoRows = $tableTwo.find('tr');

     // loop through each row in table one.
     // since table two is a clone of table one,
     // we will also manipulate table two at the same time.
     $tableOneRows.each(function(index){
         // save row for each table
         var $trOne = $(this);
         var $trTwo = $tableTwoRows.eq(index);

         // remove columns greater than divider from table one
         $trOne.children(':gt('+divider+')').remove();
         $trTwo.children(':lt('+(divider+1)+')').remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post some of the code you are using when seeing this behavior.

Comment: How are you creating and changing the ID of `#CloneTable`, from the docs: "Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead."

Comment: You are changing the ID of *all* tables to be "CloneTable", including "MainTable", with the side effect of `$tableOne` referencing both DOM elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `splitTable()` function you are calling:

```
var $tableOne = $('table').attr('id','CloneTable');
```

This sets the ID of *all* `<table>` elements to be 'CloneTable', including the one it was originally cloned from, being 'MainTable', and references both DOM elements. All changes to this jQuery object will now affect both tables. To just get the cloned table, you would use the following as you changed the ID when it was created:

```
var $tableOne = $('table#CloneTable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that shows a way of doing what you describe: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa8Wh/5/). I'm not seeing the behavior you describe (i.e. the original is modified along with some of its clones).

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var firstFive = $('#main').clone();
    var secondFive = $('#main').clone();
    $('body').append(firstFive);
    $('body').append(secondFive);
    firstFive.find('tr').each(function() { 
        $(this).find('td:gt(4)').remove()
    });
    secondFive.find('tr').each(function() { 
        $(this).find('td:lt(5)').remove()
    });
})
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="main">
    <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
        <td>1.4</td>
        <td>1.5</td>
        <td>1.6</td>
        <td>1.7</td>
        <td>1.8</td>
        <td>1.9</td>
        <td>1.10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.1</td>
        <td>2.2</td>
        <td>2.3</td>
        <td>2.4</td>
        <td>2.5</td>
        <td>2.6</td>
        <td>2.7</td>
        <td>2.8</td>
        <td>2.9</td>
        <td>2.10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** This was posted before the code sample.

Comment: The bug in the code is `var $tableOne = $('table')` - it selects both `#MainTable` and `#CloneTable` because they are both `<table>` elements, and then actually changes the ID of both to be 'CloneTable' which isn't correct, but not the problem you see here